# Privacy settings

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to edit privacy settings on SE? For example, is it possible for me to be able to make it so that people can't see the questions I ask when they view my profile?

Comment: I think that would be great if possible.

Comment: Why would you want that? Moreover, Google can probably find your questions and answers.

Comment: I cannot help but wonder: are you planning to ask particularly shameful questions, or do you consider mathematics to be a disreputable activity in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SE network is designed to create a library of *high quality* questions and answers. Keeping questions (and answers) linked to a user's profile gives an incentive for the user to maintain some level of quality of posts. E.g., having the history  of poorly worded, vague questions that are never improved may reduce the likelihood of getting answers in the future. The proposed privacy setting would remove the above incentive, which is why I think it has no chance of being implemented.

A [quote](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/296358032579911681) from network co-founder is fitting here.

> Fear is underrated as a design element. You know what site lets people post fearlessly, 100% of the time? Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Good point! People respond to incentives. A living example of No. 4 of Mankiw's ten principle of Economics.

Comment: I agree with you. I was just wondering if it is possible, it isn't because I want to post bad question as others thought... why would anyone do that?

Answer (score 10):

The proposed settings are not currently possible, and I expect they won't be possible any time soon.  A similar proposal was made on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/):

- [Is there a way I can hide my asked questions from the my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70114/is-there-a-way-i-can-hide-my-asked-questions-from-the-my-profile)

It had very little support; the only alternative provided was to ask the questions from another anonymous account.

---

Contributions on the StackExchange network fall under a rather free license: the [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  Basically, anyone may do whatever they like with your contributions, provided they give proper attribution and publish under a similar license.

The StackExchange privacy policy is given [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy):

> If you decide to post personal information in the public parts of our sites, it’s… um, public.

While this question might not pertain to personal information, the moral is more-or-less the same.

Comment: I think I should have worded my question differently as I don't mind having my questions being searchable by google or seen by other people, I am only wondering if it is possible that when a user views another use's profile, they can't see the question asked by the user being viewed.

Comment: @User79217 But why do you want this?

Comment: Sometimes I ask homework questions...

Comment: @User79217 And you don't want other people to be able to see this? If you feel like asking a question somehow makes you look bad, you should probably think an extra time before asking it.

Comment: @User79217: Once again, **why** don't you want people to be able to see the questions you ask?  You are anonymous on this site, so it's not as though anyone who actually knows you will look down on you for asking your questions.  When you mention that some of your questions are homework questions...well, honestly that makes me think that you are worried about getting caught cheating on your homework.  If that's not the correct explanation, what is?